# Update a rooted Android phone from 4.4 to newer version

Tags: rooting, 4.4-kitkat, updates, sony-xperia-z2

I have a rooted sony xperia Z2 with Android 4.4.4

Is it possible to update the phone to a newer Android version and still have root permissions?

Comment: You are a bit late. LineageOS had images for the Z2 (Sirius), however they stopped support for that device: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z2/development/rom-lineage-os-xperia-z2-sirius-t3700292

Comment: But they should be still working right?

Comment: If you are luck, yes. But I assume you will find only nightly builds, therefore the images you can find are mostly untested any may contain bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get a newer Android version, and i suggest you Do it Regardless of the Minor Bugs...

Major Bugs are a different story, but for Minor Bugs... The added Security of even Android 5.0 will be a vast improvement over Android 4.4

To make sure that you dont already have an Official OTA ( Over The Air ) Update...

Go to
• Settings
• About
• Software Updates

And try a Update in the Settings,

If your Update Application returns that you have the Latest update, you need to do the Update by Installing a Custom Recovery & Firmware..

I looked around and found a lot of Stable options for your Model...
[Official Resurrection Remix - Nougat Based](https://xdaot.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/rom7-1-2official-resurrection-remix-n-for-xperia-z2-sirius/)

This is an official build of Resurrection remix based on Android 7 ... That is already jumping a few upgrades !

Have a look around for some Stable & Daily Use builds....

Comment: Thanks for this Answere. I didnt do a official Update because it would remove the root permissions or am I wrong?
And I already found [this custom rom](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z2/development/7-x-x-carbonrom-cr-5-1-t3655016) and it sounds like the best solution even with Android 8.1.0 but I still need to get the steps right for the Installation ^^. It says Beta Version but no bugs are listed so I guess its not so bad.